# Affix h1 text to background (for basic parallax effect) pure CSS while keeping alignment in div

Tags: css

Trying to create a parallax effect with my background and site title in the `#imgh` div, but I can't figure out a way to keep the text "affixed" to the background (as if they were a single item) while keeping it in its centered position.

I know that I can achieve this by using `position: fixed;`, but then that nullifies the center alignment of my text and I don't want to lose the center align. Trying to find a way I can have both. Current code is below:

```css
#grid
{
    z-index:5;
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    
    display:grid;
    grid-template-columns:repeat(4,1fr);
    grid-template-rows:minmax(auto);
    grid-gap: 0px;
    grid-template-areas:
        "imgh imgh imgh imgh"
        "cont cont cont cont";
}

#imgh
{
    grid-area: imgh;
    background-image: url("https://www.web-designindia.com/images/header-form-banner.jpg");
    background-size: 100%;
    background-position: bottom;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    height:20vw;
    opacity: .9;
}

#imgh h1
{
    color:white;
    text-shadow: 4px 4px 8px #000;
    font-size: 5vw;
    font-family: "Bodoni MT";
    text-align: center;
    transform: translateY(55%);
}

#cont
{
    grid-area: cont;
    height:90vw;
    background-color:white;
}
```

```html
<div id="grid">
    <div id="imgh">
        <h1>Header Text</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="cont">
        <p>this is a paragraph</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Anyone know how I can get that `<h1>` to not scroll with the page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add left:50%; top:10%; transform: translate(-50%, -50%); to the h tag. While it's in padding:fixed, you could assign its fixed position through top,left,bottom,right properties then use translate to center it correctly.

```css
#grid
{
    z-index:5;
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    
    display:grid;
    grid-template-columns:repeat(4,1fr);
    grid-template-rows:minmax(auto);
    grid-gap: 0px;
    grid-template-areas:
        "imgh imgh imgh imgh"
        "cont cont cont cont";
}

#imgh
{
    grid-area: imgh;
    background-image: url("https://www.web-designindia.com/images/header-form-banner.jpg");
    background-size: 100%;
    background-position: bottom;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    height:20vw;
    opacity: .9;
}

#imgh h1
{
    color:white;
    text-shadow: 4px 4px 8px #000;
    font-size: 5vw;
    font-family: "Bodoni MT";
    text-align: center;
    position:fixed;
    left:50%;
    top:20%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

#cont
{
    grid-area: cont;
    height:90vw;
    background-color:white;
}
```

```html
<div id="grid">
    <div id="imgh">
        <h1>Header Text</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="cont">
        <p>this is a paragraph</p>
    </div>
</div>
```